# How to re-use the same java Message parameters in a loop

Tags: android, multithreading, udp, android-service, android-handler

I need a Service that runs a Thread which receives UDP data, and then sends this data to an Activity using a Handler. My code works sometimes, but there is a moment when it fails for some kind of reason that I have not been able to appreciate debugging.

**Thread running in the Service**

```
public void run() {
        //UDP initialize
        while (true) {
            //receive UDP packet
            //set Message obj and what values
            //send Message to handler
        }
}
```

**Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Obtain Message from handler
}
```

Comment: Why did you delete all the code from your original post? My answer (which I assumed helped you) is now useless. What do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep reusing the same `Message` object, basically overwriting the data in the object that has already been queued and requeueing the same object over and over again.

This code is wrong:

```
    Message msgToActivity = new Message();
    DatagramPacket packetIn = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    while (true) {
        receiveSocket.receive(packetIn);
        msgToActivity.obj = new String(receiveData, 0, packetIn.getLength());
        msgToActivity.what = 0;
        LogComActivity.logcomHandler.sendMessage(msgToActivity);
    }
```

You are creating a single `Message` object and then modifying it and queueing it inside the loop.

Do this instead:

```
    DatagramPacket packetIn = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    while (true) {
        receiveSocket.receive(packetIn);
        Message msgToActivity = Message.obtain();
        msgToActivity.obj = new String(receiveData, 0, packetIn.getLength());
        msgToActivity.what = 0;
        LogComActivity.logcomHandler.sendMessage(msgToActivity);
    }
```

This code gets a new `Message` object each time inside the loop, but requests the `Message` object from a global pool of recycled objects instead of creating a new one each time.

---

Also, this call (inside `handleMessage())`:

```
this.obtainMessage();
```

is useless, as you don't do anything with the returned `Message` object. You don't need that code. Delete it.